# PHP - MySQLi INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

I must to send an INSERT query to MySQL database, assuming all the variables are correctly setted, I'm using this code:

```
 $check_alrd_sent = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id_prod =" . $id_prod . " AND id_user = " . $current_usr . " LIMIT 1");
$check = mysqli_fetch_all($check_alrd_sent);

if ($check != NULL) {
    $check_err = 1;
} else {
    $ins_rev = $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `reviews` (`ID` ,`ID_prod` ,`ID_user` ,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES (NULL , " . $id_prod .",  " . $current_usr . ", " . $review . ",  " . $rating . ");");
    $ins_result = 1;
}
mysqli_free_result($check_alrd_sent);
```

The `$ins_result` variable is correcly set as result, as I can see using `var_dump()` but now rows are insert in database.

The strange thing is that if I call the MySQL error log can clearly see that the insert is sent to the database correctly as:

```
42 Query     INSERT INTO `reviews` (`ID` ,`ID_prod` ,`ID_user` ,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES (NULL , 11,  1, asd,  4)
```

But it doesn't appear in the table.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: first of all - wrap all character field values by quotes, and will SELECT always returns NULL? I can't see the code that opens the connection to the mysql, may be you didn't select a database properly?

Comment: @Wizard I'm using `$mysqli = new mysqli ($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName) or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());` all the variables are correctly set. I'm using PHPmyAdmin and the generated SELECT display an empty table. I've tried to append ` `dbname`,`reviews` ` but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in your **INSERT Statement:**

1. Value of review column is a string so you need to use quotes around review VALUE.
2. I think ID is an AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL field. So no need to use in INSERT Query.

**Modified query:**

```
INSERT INTO `reviews` 
( `ID_prod`, `ID_user` ,`review` ,`stars`) 
VALUES (11, 1, "asd", 4)
```

Comment: I say lose all the crazy back ticks and single quotes. You're also seeing why parameter used queries are favored so much.

Comment: Make sure u r using backticks not quotes  'reviews'  should be `reviews` @andreaem

Comment: You're right, the ID is auto-increment, was wondering that using null was correct, anyway the since the output is `92 Query     INSERT INTO 'reviews' ('ID_prod' ,'ID_user' ,'review' ,'stars') VALUES (11,  1, 'asd',  4)` according to the mysql error log, the insert won't to be done, and see nothing in the table

Comment: @andreaem run this query manually in phpmyadmin INSERT INTO 'reviews' ('ID_prod' ,'ID_user' ,'review' ,'stars') VALUES (11, 1, 'asd', 4)

Comment: Here is my query "INSERT INTO `reviews` ( `ID_prod`, `ID_user` ,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES (". $id_prod .",  " . $current_usr . ", `" . $review . "`,  " . $rating . ");" @devpro your first query (in top reply) is working, the second in the comment nope.

Comment: Second is not working becuase it contains quotes not backticks u can not use quotes around table name and column name @andreaem

Comment: @andreaem use this in code-----    $ins_rev = $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `reviews` (`ID_prod` ,`ID_user`
,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES ( '" . $id_prod ."', ' " . $current_usr . "', '" .
$review . "',  '" . $rating . "');");

Comment: Understand, but i really don't understand why isn't working in my PHP code, as the output still the same `INSERT INTO `itriedit`,`reviews` ( `ID_prod`, `ID_user` ,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES (11,1,`asd`,5)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102823/discussion-between-devpro-and-andreaem).

Comment: @devpro Damn It's Working! Thanks a lot! so the error was in the `reviews` table name that must be whit out ` ... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your time @devpro

Answer (score 1):

varchar fields must be in 2 quota, so `review` field must be in 2 `'`:

```
$ins_rev = $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `reviews` (`ID` ,`ID_prod` ,`ID_user`
,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES (NULL , '" . $id_prod ."', ' " . $current_usr . "', '" .
$review . "',  '" . $rating . "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your output, "asd" is not in single quotes. That would be invalid SQL. Should also think about converting to non-deprecated SQL functions such as PDO.

Comment: Thanks I've made the changes but the result is the same, no insert yet, the errlog say `52 Query     INSERT INTO 'reviews' (`ID` ,`ID_prod` ,`ID_user` ,`review` ,`stars`) VALUES (NULL , 11,  1, 'asd',  2)` so should be correct

Comment: Shows a back tick after (ID - that's not valid.

Comment: sorry, this is cause Stackoverflow convert ` in code string,  was a paste error